# Editing report in ms access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I want to show 'modify' and 'delete record' button against each record in REPORT VIEW of MS Access. Upon clicking modify button the record must be modified in report view rather than going to Form or Table.

Comment: OK, so what have you tried and what specific problem did you have it getting it to work?

Comment: No idea. totally blank for this.....

Answer (score 2):

You should be doing this in a form as you can make the form look like a report or print using a report after you are done editing with the form.  However,you can add a delete button to each record and get that to work with either a form or a report. For instance: add two buttons to the detail section of a report.

[image]

[image]

[image]

From the button event handlers you have access to the form properties and controls including the field values of the record the button is inside so:

```
Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()
'DoCmd.RunSQL ("Delete * FROM Table1 WHERE ID = " & Me.ID) 'has warning message
CurrentDb.Execute ("Delete * FROM Table1 WHERE ID = " & Me.ID)

' Show changes
Me.Requery
End Sub
```

Inside the modify button you could replace the delete statement with an update statement but where do you get the new values?  You can make some inputs appear in the reports header but most of the time you just open a record editing form and pass the current records ID.  A common case for instance is the user of the database is entering orders and realizes the customer hasn't been added to the database yet: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MzDcj0Mhd4k